# Clarifications for SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I am implementing a Database for my (beginner/Android) application.

It is not clear to me if the

```
SQLiteOpenHelper
```

is meant to create the Database (physically, writing the .db/.sql file) with

```
super()
```

or if it still up to me to create such file, and this Class is there just to manage opening,closing,updating the Database.

In case it is like this, there's no other way to have a class that manage DBs automatically, e.g. just passing name of the file (apart from doing it myself ^_^ )

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SQLiteOpenHelper` will create the database file before calling `onCreate()` of your `SQLiteOpenHelper` subclass.

Comment: OK. So what's wrong in trying to check the existance of the database with a 
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
The application basically crashes as soon as I ask for the DB.
Are you forced to at least create a Table in the DB to "activate" it?

Comment: @carmelo: "So what's wrong in trying to check the existance of the database with a SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();" -- nothing. "The application basically crashes as soon as I ask for the DB" -- presumably, your app has bugs, perhaps in your `onCreate()` implementation. Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the LogCat view in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you. Unfortunately that does not help.
The LogCat trace is long to show here, but basically it fires an Exception related to "calling recursively the getReadableDatabase".

java.lang.IllegalStateException: getReadableDatabase called recursively

Thank you.

Comment: @2dvisio: Don't call `getWritebleDatabase()` (or `getReadableDatabase()`, for that matter) from *inside* `onCreate()` or `onUpgrade()` of your `SQLiteOpenHelper` subclass. For starters, you do not need it, as the database *by definition* is created for you by this point in time. And, you are passed the `SQLiteDatabase` objects as a parameter to both of those methods. Calling `getWriteableDatabase()` anywhere else is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NiceQL](https://github.com/Auxx/niceql) library and forget about manual database creation. There are a lot of quirks in Android APIs regarding creating databases and they arenot properly documented. NiceQL covers them all.